# Unable to get the updated state when using React useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to perform a state change and after that I want to make an API request. But since useState is asyncronous, I cannot do that. I tried using the `useEffect()` hook but it is impossible to find the exact array element that was changed.

In `toggleCompleted()` I am getting the old value for `updatedTask` because `setTasks` is asyncronous.

**App.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

    const toggleCompleted = id => {
        setTasks(
            tasks.map(task => {
                return task.id === id
                    ? { ...task, isCompleted: !task.isCompleted }
                    : task
            })
        )

        // This will get the old value
        const updatedTask = tasks.find(task => task.id === id)
        
        // PUT request here
        fetch(`${api_url}/tasks/${id}`, {
             method: 'PUT',
             body: JSON.stringify(updatedTask)
        })
    }
}

export default App
```

I also tried using the `useEffect` hook, but I am getting the whole `tasks` array and not the individual task that was updated so I cannot use this to make a `PUT` request to my backend API.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // unable to get the exact one task that was updated
}, [tasks])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

    const toggleCompleted = id => {
        let updatedTask = tasks.filter(task => task.id === id)
        updatedTask.isCompleted = !updatedTask.isCompleted

        // PUT request here
        fetch(`${api_url}/tasks/${id}`, {
             method: 'PUT',
             body: JSON.stringify(updatedTask)
        })

        setState(tasks.map(task => task.id === id ? updatedTask : task))
    }
}

export default App
```

This should solve your problem.
Basically, we capture the task we want to update, manipulate it however we want, then finally set the state.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to wait for the API call to finish (`await`) in order to be able to `setTasks`. I wanted to first set the tasks and and only then do the API call.

Comment: If we're going for "best" approach then both are not really fitting. Who says the API call was successful? We should actually wrap it in a `try/catch` and only set the tasks if it didn't fail.

Comment: I disagree. I makes for a bad UX to force users to wait for the API call to finish before showing the results. Take a look at how facebook does it. I first updates the UI, before the API call has finished. And then if the API call fails - it updates the UI again and shows an error message.

Comment: Well yes, you can update the UI before the API call to indicate that something is happening, then update it again dependent on the result. I didn't rule that out.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do. I wanted to first add the task to UI (and maybe show a message like `saving...`) and then perform the API call. So the user will see their message getting posted as soon as they press the button. Then if for some reason the API fails, I can updated the UI and show an error message. But `setTasks` is synchronous so you will see the old value if you try to access tasks right after setting them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring my code to where I first get and update the element which is used both for updating the state and also for making the API call.

```
const toggleReminder = id => {
    let updatedTask = tasks.find(task => task.id === id)
    updatedTask.isCompleted = !updatedTask.isCompleted

    setTasks(
        tasks.map(task => {
            return task.id === id
                ? updatedTask
                : task
        })
    )

    fetch(`${api_url}/tasks/${id}`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedTask)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([])

    const toggleCompleted = async (id) => {
        const currentTask = tasks.find(task => task.id === id);
        const updatedTask = {...currentTask, isCompleted: !currentTask.isCompleted}; 
        
        await fetch(`${api_url}/tasks/${id}`, {
             method: 'PUT',
             body: JSON.stringify(updatedTask)
        });

        setTasks(tasks.map(task => task.id === id?updatedTask :task));
    }
}

export default App
```

you can use normal function instead of async / await and put the setTasks in .then but I think it's simpler.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you have to wait for the API call to finish (`await`) in order to be able to `setTasks`. I wanted to first set the tasks and and only then do the API call.